# Ram Compatibilty

Tags: memory, compatibility, comparison

I wish to upgrade my laptop from 6GB ram to 8GB ram. Currently installed is

Type    DDR3
Size    4096 MBytes
Manufacturer    Samsung
Max Bandwidth   PC3-12800 (800 MHz)
Part Number M471B5173DB0-YK0

Now, I have a 4gb 2rx8 pc3-12800s-11-11-FP from my old laptop. Would these rams work together? I'm trying to understand about the different speeds and I'm not sure if it will. I would seriously appreciate any help I get.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they're both DDR3 and have the same frequency, so there shouldn't be any problem, assuming that your laptop's motherboard supports 8GB of RAM.